# Chinese version of "action speaks louder than words"

Tags: translation, idioms

What is the chinese version of the common idiom:

> Action speaks louder than words

Google translate gives this:

> 行动胜于雄辩

Is this correct? And what other alternatives are there?

Comment: 行胜于言 ..........

Comment: My own version --- "一动胜万语"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idioms translating from english to chinese vary **a lot**. But I feel the most common one is:

> 事实胜于雄辩

Supported by:

- [Reverso](https://context.reverso.net/%25E7%25BF%25BB%25E8%25AF%2591/%25E4%25B8%25AD%25E6%2596%2587-%25E8%258B%25B1%25E8%25AF%25AD/%25E4%25BA%258B%25E5%25AE%259E%25E8%2583%259C%25E4%25BA%258E%25E9%259B%2584%25E8%25BE%25A9&ved=2ahUKEwjRydyYhtX4AhXF1zgGHQqzBscQFnoECAsQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3UZPuiod7IyWwfnX67_BNg)
- [Dictionary](https://en.bab.la/dictionary/english-chinese/actions-speak-louder-than-words)
- [Purpleculture](https://www.purpleculture.net/dictionary-details/?word=%E4%BA%8B%E5%AE%9E%E8%83%9C%E4%BA%8E%E9%9B%84%E8%BE%A9)

Alternatives:

- `行动胜于雄辩`
- `行动胜于言语`

Answer (score 1):

You could try these two:

不务空名
not seek empty name

务：追求。
matter: seek
切实地工作，不追求虚名。
work conscientiously, don't seek a false reputation.

菲言厚行
few words much action

菲: 微薄，引申为少；
poor: scanty, meagre extended meaning few;
厚：指多。**少说多做**。
thick: refers to many. little speak much action